# How to call a function in a smart contract from Truffle (or anywhere else)?

Tags: solidity, truffle

PSA: I'm new to Solidity/Truffle and I'm hoping you guys won't be too harsh on me

I'm trying to figure out how call a function that only the smart contract owner can call. The reason why I want to do this, is because I want to be able to self destruct my contract whenever I want. I've seen guides on how to write the function itself, but that's not exactly in question for me. I just want to know how I can call it as the owner of the smart contract.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: what I currently have

```
function kaboom() public onlyOwner
        selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, what you need is a function modifier which will work as a check mechanism before letting the rest of the function to executed.

From the solidity documentation:

> Modifiers can be used to change the behavior of functions in a
> declarative way. For example, you can use a modifier to automatically
> check a condition prior to executing the function.

You can find the example in the following [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_function_modifiers.htm#:%7E:text=Function%20Modifiers%20are%20used%20to,modifier%20with%20or%20without%20parameter.&text=The%20function%20body%20is%20inserted,the%20definition%20of%20a%20modifier.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording, I'm trying to find out how to call a function in the contract sometime in the future (in this case `selfdestruct()`). I already have the onlyOwner modifier attached to my function.